# Sums and subtotals in SELECT... HAVING result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the sum of each customer's orders separately, but I'm actually getting the sum of *all* the orders. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT c.customerNumber, sum( r.quantityOrdered * r.priceEach ) AS sum
FROM customers c, orders o, orderdetails r
WHERE c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
AND o.orderNumber = r.orderNUmber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber
HAVING COUNT( o.orderNumber ) <=3
```

Comment: Do you get any results at all? Can you show a estimated output?

Comment: What do you expect the HAVING clause to be doing? If you want only the customers with 3 or less orders, then it should be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderNumber) <= 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `JOIN` as it is the standardised way of writing the syntax. Makes it easier to read.

```
SELECT c.customerNumber, sum( r.quantityOrdered * r.priceEach ) AS sum
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o      ON  c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
LEFT JOIN orderdetails r ON  o.orderNumber = r.orderNUmber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber
HAVING COUNT( o.orderNumber ) <=3
```

When you use `LEFT JOIN`, this will give the results of the table `customers`, even if they dont have any recods in the `orders` and `orderdetails`.

Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks ok to me other than the `HAVING` clause.  I don't know what you are really trying to achieve with `HAVING COUNT( o.orderNumber ) <=3`.  Do you really want customers with order of 3 or less? Have you tried using :

```
SELECT c.customerNumber, sum(r.quantityOrdered * r.priceEach) AS sum
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
INNER JOIN orderdetails r ON o.orderNumber = r.orderNUmber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber
```